# How to indicate a picker control is going to be opened on a form field

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

I'm doing a form field on an app and need to included a drop down at the end of some of the text fields. For the android version I'll be using the material design standard as below.

[image]

I see that iOS doesn't endorse using a drop down but would show i picker instead. How do I visually indicate on the form that a picker control is going to be opened on a form field from a certain link or icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose the picker, the iOS [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1) state that you should place it inline with the content:

> **As much as possible, display a picker inline with the content.** It’s best when users can avoid navigating to a different view to use a picker.

But unfortunately this wastes a lot of precious space, I am not sure why Apple would prefer this over a simple dropdown. But if you have the space it should be ok.

An alternative that I can imagine to work for you would be using a **list element which opens a table view** with mutiple options: 
[image]

Or just display the picker in this new view, if you feel it is really necessary.